# NSubstitute auto-mocking certain types only

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I've noticed that NSubstitute auto-mocks the following types:

- Array
- IObservable
- String
- Task

Although I know this happens, I can't find the *reason* for picking these types. Why not leave `String` null? Or include collections instead of just `Array`?

For example:

```
var crazyInterface = Substitute.For<ICrazyInterface>();

FileInfo[] folderContents = crazyInterface.FolderContents(@"C:\folder");
IObservable<FileInfo> fileObserver = crazyInterface.CreateNewFileObservable();
string fileHash = crazyInterface.FileHash(@"C:\folder\file.txt");
Task<byte[]> fileContents = crazyInterface.ReadFileContentsAsync(@"C:\folder\file.txt");
```

All get a mock implemented for them, whereas `List<T>` would be null (or any other reference type).

The [source code](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute) gives no indication as to the reason just implements to auto-mocks in the [AutoValues](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/tree/master/Source/NSubstitute/Routing/AutoValues) folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: specific auto-mocked types just got added as people wanted them and we felt the convenience would outweigh any confusion caused by returning a real value when a mock or `default(T)` may have been expected.

---

In case anyone's interested here's the longer, hopefully-partially-accurate story of this feature's evolution as I recall it.

NSubstitute started off returning `default(T)` for everything. This gets painful for cases where we have chains of calls, so we added auto-mocking for interface types. This is a fairly safe operation - unlike with classes there is no potential for real code to run, say, from the constructor call, or by inadvertently calling a non-virtual method. For example, `mySub.SomeAutoSub().DoStuff()` could run real code or not based on the return type of `SomeAutoSub()`.

The next level of safety is classes that have all virtual members, and a default constructor. The documentation refers to theses as [pure virtual classes](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/auto-and-recursive-mocks/). Having virtual members means if we dig in to an auto-subbed instance we can't accidentally call real code. Now this will still run real code via the constructor, but it doesn't take parameters and so we can assume (read: cross-fingers and hope) the default behaviour will do something sensible rather than doing anything terrible.

Finally, there are the exceptional cases you pointed out like `Array` and `Task`. These were added completely ad hoc based on feedback when we felt the convenience would outweigh any confusion caused. The main thing we want to avoid with these is returning a real value when a mock was expected. NSubstitute doesn't work well if you accidentally call `.Returns` on something that isn't a mock.

`Strings`, `Arrays` and `Tasks` meet this criteria. You can't mock these types so having a default value that works sensibly in tests seems reasonable. I found I often ran into string ops that blew up because of the null default, so I added that one for convenience. Others wanted a default `Task` that worked sensibly and so added that. I can't remember the reasoning behind not auto-subbing collections (possibly because some people use mocked versions of `IList<T>`, where providing a specific implementation like `List<T>` is easier enough to explicitly stub?).

I think we can get away with some inconsistency here because we are in the context of tests -- if we need a specific value or behaviour we'll explicitly stub it out. Otherwise we'll get a default value that hopefully won't get in the way.

If you would like additional things auto-subbed please ping the [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/nsubstitute). It's a bit harder to make potentially-breaking changes like this now but if there's a compelling case for a particular type we can look at adding it in.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I release you're a core committer to the project so appreciate the time taken out of your day to answer this.